# Position/order of dealing post pre-flop

Tags: poker-theory, betting-position

During pre-flop I understand that one has position over others who are seated in an earlier position than him; and one is out of position to players seated at a later position than himself, but this gets affected going into flop according to the ways different players act. So how is your position/order of card-dealing decided for streets post pre-flop?

For example, if a player sitting at the Cut-off makes the final raise pre-flop and all others called including the Button, who will be acting first on the flop? If no one raised and everyone called the Blinds' open on the pre-flop, who will be acting first on the flop in this case? Or if there are several re-raises between several players on the preflop, which player will be acting first on the next street?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The betting behavior of players does not affect the order in which action takes place in later betting rounds.  When new community cards are dealt (flop, turn and river), the new betting round starts with the first player left of the dealer, if he/she hasn't folded in the previous betting round.  In the examples you give, nobody folds so this would be the small blind.